# lualatex removed token?

Tags: luatex

I had some code that compiled previous but just installed latest miktex and I get errors now. They involve the use of token. It seems token.command_name no longer exists. In the old help it was there but in the new help it is gone. I can't seem to find anyone mentioning how to migrate to what is new(which I can't find)

lualatex: attempt to call field `command_name` a nil value

Again, this code worked fine before and was a deeply used command(so it is not on my side of the code).

Any ideas what happened and what to do about it? I need to wrap tex commands such as defining, existence, etc tex macros on the lua side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [recent LuaTeX (>=0.95.0)](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/luatex/base/luatex.pdf) some functions of the [`token` library](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/luatex/base/luatex.pdf##364) have been removed and promoted to properties of the token itself.  In older LuaTeX the following worked

```
\directlua{
  local t = token.create("relax")
  local csname = token.command_name(t)
  tex.sprint(csname)
}
\bye
```

With recent LuaTeX however, we need to replace `token.command_name(t)` by `t.cmdname`.

```
\directlua{
  local t = token.create("relax")
  local csname = t.cmdname
  tex.sprint(csname)
}
\bye
```

Answer (score 1):

A look in the newest [LuaTeX manual](http://www.luatex.org/svn/trunk/manual/luatex.pdf) suggests that `command_name` was removed. Take a look at pages 169–170 of the manual: they mention `cmdname`. Is its functionality what you are looking for?